# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints runtime error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

I get this error in runtime for my ios(UIKit) application. It is coming from `UITableView`. The app runs without constraint errors and with the expected behavior.

I've seen other questions regarding the same error but should I leave this error as it is?

The error is partially complaining about my two `UITableView` which are connected through a cell(First table uses 1.6 as the aspect ratio and second view uses .55 for width/size). I'm not sure how this can be fixed since there is no problem and these views are separate.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575860 UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width == 1.6*UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575770 V:|-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7f8795f47080]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575810 V:[UIStackView:0x7f8795f47080]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575950 UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width == 0.55*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001573f20 'UISV-alignment' UILabel:0x7f8795f47210.bottom == UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575ae0 'UISV-alignment' UILabel:0x7f8795f47210.top == UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000150cdc0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7f8795f47080.top == UILabel:0x7f8795f47210.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000150ce60 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UILabel:0x7f8795f47210]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f8795f47080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575cc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50.height == 154.333   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575c70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50.width == 390   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575860 UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width == 1.6*UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: First you say "The app runs without constraint errors and with the expected behavior". Then you show a constraint error. So which is it then?

Comment: This error shows on the console but the app build and runs without issue

Comment: CLearly you have applied 2 constraints to UIImageView's width 1. `UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width == 1.6*UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.height` and 2. `UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width == 0.55*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50.width` how do you expect both the constraint to be satisfied, you remove one of them and it will work fine or else iOS will do that for you on your behalf while running and prints a constraint break error log on console

Comment: Note that there are probably other constraints that specify image height, thus creating the conflict.

Comment: Changing the constraint priority of one of them to 999 solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: That is not solving the issue, this just tells which constraint will be broken if necessary. Like Sandeep said: Your constraints are wrong because you're setting the width twice

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're setting constraints to the same view twice:

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575860 **UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width** == 1.6*UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.height   (active)>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001575950 **UIImageView:0x7f8795f474f0.width** == 0.55*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8795f46b50.width   (active)>"